# Raspberry PI won't boot with Logitech c615 webcam attached

Tags: boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ that i use to run OctoPi for my 3d Printer, I have recently added a Logitech C615 webcam to monitor the prints however when the webcam is connected the Pi won't boot. Nothing displays on the screen and I get no network activity. I'm network booting the Pi however it also fails to boot with no display output when an SD card is used. If I boot the Pi then connect the webcam then everything works fine but booting with the webcam connected prevents it from even attempting to boot.

I've measured the current draw and it never goes over 0.33A with a power supply capable of delivering 2.4A so it doesn't appear to be power related.

Comment: If you have (or can borrow) a powered hub, it's worth using that to rule power out.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I'm using a 60W USB PSU, i've got a USB Current & Voltage monitor i've used to measure the actual current and it never goes over 0.33A so i'm certain it's not a power issue.

Comment: You might want to try a different Raspberry. I had different mileage with Logitech Webcams to, see http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Raspberry_PI_WebCam